# Publish excel vba workbook to webpage

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel vba workbook. Most of the workbook is password protected. I'd like to expose the public worksheets and their macro functionality through a website. Is it possible in some way to integrate an excel vba workbook with a website? Failing that integrate it with share point?

Comment: Macros will not run in a web browser.

Comment: @Tim Williams - so there's no way of having an application leaverage them? Like having the web app hosted on Windows server and hit the excel macro in background?

Comment: Running Excel on the server is not recommended - it's not built for that purpose.

Comment: @Tim Williams - I do imagine it would be fickle running as an engine behind the scenes. I've started to look at easasoftwares conversion tool